# Generate pure JPA annotated POJOs from existing classes

Tags: java, hibernate, jpa

I’m in an existing codebase that contains 500+ JPA annotated entity classes. These classes also contain business logic and other tightly coupled dependencies. I want to extract these classes to another project and start clean with just pure JPA class entities.

I already tried to generate the POJOS from the database schema with hbm2java (maven-plugin), which resulted in about 1300+ generated classes and loses the inheritance hierarchy. This is mainly due to the plugin not recognising the Inheritance Strategy of the existing entity classes.

Any suggestions on how to produce pure JPA annotated POJOs with the correct inheritance hierarchy of the existing classes?

Comment: I suppose your database has not pk/fk restrictions in your schema. The plugin just doesn't know how the inheritance should be because it is no source for this information.

Comment: Can't you just copy over the code and remove all methods except for getters/setters?